# Design a (r-1)'s complement system with minimum cost when r = 5 using any 2-input AND, 2-input OR and NOT gate

Tags: digital-logic

after making the truth table I am unable to make the appropriate circuit diagram.
I don't know how am I supposed to produce the r-1's complement as the output.

Comment: This sounds like homework: the point is to learn how to answer such questions.

Comment: This is not homework. I assure you that. This was one of the questions in my test and I am unable to design the logic circuit.

Answer (score 0):

convert the input value in base 5 to binary using 3 bits, and then should be easy. Use k map for every bit of output to get the minimum cost.

Comment: you are totally correct. But I was asking about the circuit. I don't know how am I supposed to produce a 3-bit number through logic gates